# My CS50 problem set1 - File Extensions program is not returning correct code when run

Tags: python, if-statement, cs50

I am trying to solve this problem on cs50 python course:
*"In a file called extensions.py, implement a program that prompts the user for the name of a file and then outputs that file’s media type if the file’s name ends, case-insensitively, in any of these suffixes: .jpeg, .png etc..
If the file’s name ends with some other suffix or has no suffix at all, output application/octet-stream instead, which is a common default."*

Program:

```
name = input("Give me a filename:").lower()

if ".gif" or ".png" or ".jpeg" or ".jpg" in name:
    print(f'image/{name.split(".")[-1]}')
elif ".pdf" or ".zip" in name:
    print(f'application/{name.split(".")[-1]}')
elif ".txt" in name:
    print("text/plain")
else: 
    print("application/octet-stream")
```

**ISSUE:** When I run input "file.zip", instead of output **"application/zip"**, I get **"image/zip"**. If I input **"file.gif/.png/.jpeg/.jpg"** the output is correct.

What is wrong in my program?

I have tried to modify like this but still, output is not correct:

```
if ".gif" or ".png" or ".jpeg" or ".jpg" in name:
    name = name.split(".")[-1]
    print(f'image/{name}')
elif ".pdf" or ".zip" in name:
    name = name.split(".")[-1]
    print(f'application/{name}')
elif ".txt" in name:
    print("text/plain")
else: 
    print("application/octet-stream")
```

Comment: `or` and `in` don't combine together in the way that you think. `a or b in c` is not shorthand for `a in c or b in c`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if ".gif" or ".png" or ".jpeg" or ".jpg" in name:
```

is not the correct way to do it. This is:

```
ext = name.rsplit('.', 1)[-1].lower()

if ext in ("gif", "png", "jpeg", "jpg"):
    print(f'image/{ext}')
elif ext in ("pdf", "zip"):
    print(f'application/{ext}')
elif ext == "txt"
    print("text/plain")
else: 
    print("application/octet-stream")
```

Explaination:

```
'a' or 'b' or 'c' in name
```

evaluates as: if 'a' evaluates to True, or 'b' evaluates to True, or 'c' is in `name`, which is not what it reads in English.

Another problem with this is that `name` is not really the right place to search. Even if it was written as `".gif" in name or ".png" in name or ...`, the search string could occur elsewhere in the string. E.g., the file name could be `picture.jpg.zip` - which will falsely match the image condition.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've modified your code to use the .split() instead of .rsplit() (out of curiosity) and the results are still correct. Does it matter on this specific problem if I split from right side or left side?

Comment: @PhillyBilly it's only a matter of efficiency. If there are multiple dots in the name, I'm only interested in the rightmost one - so, `.rsplit` will be marginally faster

Answer (score 0):

Use `endswith()`:

```
name = input('Give me a filename: ').lower()

if name.endswith(('.gif', '.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg')):
    print(f'image/{name.split(".")[-1]}')
elif name.endswith(('.pdf', '.zip')):
    print(f'application/{name.split(".")[-1]}')
elif name.endswith('.txt'):
    print("text/plain")
else:
    print("application/octet-stream")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to solve this problem set but here is the final working solution I'd like to share with you. I used the dictionary and list inside the code to simplify the problem and execute the tests.
Lets take a look at it:

```
user_input = input("File name: ").strip().lower()

file_name, *file_extensions = user_input.split(".")

#the * with file_extensions will put all the text after first '.' to a list named as file_extensions. then we will call the last item of the list using [-1]

#if file_extensions exists, then file_type is the last item in the list

if file_extensions: 
    file_type = file_extensions[-1]
else:
    #otherwise the file_type is empty and for the successful test of cs50 

    # with no extension print "application/octet-stream"
    file_type = ""
    print("application/octet-stream")

    #made a dictionary with all the file types with key values as taken from the user input
file_type_dictionary = {

    'gif': 'image/gif',


    'jpeg': 'image/jpeg',

    'jpg': 'image/jpeg',

    'pdf': 'application/pdf',

    'txt': 'text/plain',

    'zip': 'application/zip',

    'png': 'image/png',

    'bin': 'application/octet-stream',

}
#if file_type matches inside dictionary print file_type otherwise print 
"" mean nothing to avoid errors in submit50

result = file_type_dictionary.get(file_type, '')

print(result)
```